# Subscribe/unsubscribe option for users email

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, 2016

Looking for a way to add a button to either unsubscribe or subscribe to a list.

Basically user will enter their email and it will populate a list which I can use to create a distribution list. In a similar fashion a user can toggle to unsubscribe as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you need a toggle button, per my knowledge there is no out of box solution for you.

You will need to do some development work to create the Toggle Button and use it to edit the list where you store emails for the distribution list.

As a workaround, you may try to use the **Follow** feature to do so. Ask users who want to subscribe follow certain user, then get the followers list.

Example and references:
[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-followers-or-following-users-from-sharepoint-user-p2/#:~:text=Retrieve%20Current%20User%20Followers&text=With%20people%20manager%20object%2C%20use,information%20of%20user%20and%20%24follower](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-followers-or-following-users-from-sharepoint-user-p2/#:%7E:text=Retrieve%20Current%20User%20Followers&text=With%20people%20manager%20object%2C%20use,information%20of%20user%20and%20%24follower).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/following-people-and-content-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18580.sharepoint-2013-how-to-get-following-and-followers-of-user-by-using-jsom-or-javascript.aspx